# Win32 Form for dll injection

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, inject, dll-injection

I created a dll with form in it, and when we inject the dll the form open.
But the problem it when I do it, the process that I injected to, stuck and I can't with him noting.

here what I did.

```
DWORD WINAPI MessageLoop(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    hWindow = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, DLGPROC(WindowProc));

    MSG Msg;
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the injection:

```
DWORD WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPSTR lpszReserved)
{
    if(dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MessageLoop(hInstance), 0, 0, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

@Remy Lebeau :

```
DWORD WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPSTR lpszReserved)
{
    if(dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        CreateThread(0, 0, &MessageLoop, hInstance, 0, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your call to `CreateThread()` is wrong. You are not passing the address of `MessageLoop()` to it, you are actually calling `MessageLoop()` instead.  Try this:

```
DWORD WINAPI MessageLoop(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE) lpParameter;
    ...
}

CreateThread(0, 0, &MessageLoop, hInstance, 0, 0);
```

BTW, `CreateThread()` is not safe to call in `DllMain()`. This is clearly stated in various MSDN documentation. You will have to move it out of `DllMain()`, such as by having the DLL export a separate function that calls `CreateThread()` internally, and then have your injection code call the exported function after the DLL has been loaded into memory.

Comment: Now the process crash when I inject the dll. Maybe like you said cuz the CreateThread(). any idea how to make it works with other function ?

Comment: How are you injecting the DLL to begin with? Did you move `CreateThread()` out of `DllMain()`, where it does not belong?

Comment: Should I use a void function for this ? or what ?

Comment: I edited the original post and added how the dllmain looks now.

Comment: `MessageLoop(hInstance)` is calling `MessageLoop()` and then passing the return value to `CreateThread()`.  That is why the app is freezing - your code is displaying the dialog and running the message loop in the context of the thread that is loading the DLL, not in the context of your own worker thread. That is why you need to use `&MessageLoop, hInstance` instead. You are telling `CreateThread()` what function to call and what parameter to pass to it. But and as I said, you need to take `CreateThread()` out of `DllMain()` completely. It is not safe to use it there.